# how can I reflect on the Performance Monitor a performance counter created via code?

Tags: c#, performancecounter, performance-monitor

I am creating a performance counter via code. For reference CounterName, CategoryName, CategoryHelp, InstanceName are const strings.

```
//creating the category
var counterData = new CounterCreationDataCollection();

            var counterCreationData = new CounterCreationData(CounterName, "", CounterType);
            counterData.Add(counterCreationData);

            PerformanceCounterCategory.Create(CategoryName, CategoryHelp, 
                PerformanceCounterCategoryType.MultiInstance, counterData);

//creating the counter
_counter = new PerformanceCounter(CategoryName, CounterName, InstanceName, false);
_counter.Increment();
```

How can I reflect on the Performance Monitor my performance counter created via code?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You simply need to click on the + button. If everything works perfect in C# code you will be able to see your PC entry there. From that window add your counter.
Are you trying to look programmatic way to add to perfmon UI?

Comment: I just wanted to see it reflected on all performance counter available but I can't. When I run my code and list the counter with my name with power shell it display my counter there get-counter -list MyCounterName*

Comment: what you mean by "all performance counter" available? Are you trying to control/change existing performance counters?